# Using the dangerous IN clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Why does SQL server behave this way. I am running this on SQL 2005.

The IN clause does not validate the column names in the sub query but validates it
against the table name in the outer query.  Here is an example of getting

```
Create table #table1(col1 int, col2 char(10), col3 char(15));

Create table #table2(col10 int, col11 char(10), col2 char(15));


insert into #table1(col1, col2, col3)
select 1, 'one', 'three'

insert into #table1(col1, col2, col3)
select 2, 'two', 'three'

insert into #table1(col1, col2, col3)
select 3, 'three', 'four'


insert into #table2(col10, col11, col2)
select 1, 'one', 'three'

insert into #table2(col10, col11, col2)
select 2, 'two', 'three'

insert into #table2(col10, col11, col2)
select 3, 'three', 'four'


select * from #table1
where col1 IN
(select col1 from #table2)
```

Where as if I just select the "select col1 from #table2" and run it spits an error

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'col1'.
```

Comment: This allows you to filter data in subquery by outer query and return expressions using this data. It is too much to expect Sql Server to deem `col1` invalid but `col1*col10` valid.

Comment: Based on the definition of `#table2` there is no `col1` in that table - that would be why there is an error.

Comment: You could have just looked at the query plan to work out that it's not considering col1 to be in the second table - see [this screenshot](http://i49.tinypic.com/2rfvl37.png) - look at the Predicate section.

Comment: Btw, good that you've provided sample data +1. Next time you may additionally want to post a sql-fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb89e/6/0

Comment: The First Rule of Programming: [`SELECT` isn't broken](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)

Comment: Create another test where the table data don't match.

Answer (score 13):

Why? Because it's frequently *useful* to be able to reference columns from the outer query in subqueries. There's no setting you can use to turn off this behaviour, but if you get into the habit of using aliases, you should avoid most problems with it:

```
select * from #table1 t1
where t1.col1 IN
(select t2.col1 from #table2 t2)
```

Will produce an error.

Comment: Beat me to it; was going to show the explicit implementation as you did as well.

Comment: Damien, thanks for the explanation. Most of the times I would use aliases when working with multiple tables but this particular SQL behavior threw me off, I'll have to remember to use aliases at all times.

Answer (score 6):

It's not the IN clauses that's the problem.

This:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM #table1
 WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col1 
                  FROM #table2)
```

...works, because the optimizer is assumes `col1` to be from #table1.  If you use table aliases so there's no ambiguity:

```
SELECT t1.* 
  FROM #table1 t1
 WHERE t1.col1 IN (SELECT t2.col1 
                     FROM #table2 t2)
```

...you'll get the `Msg 207: Invalid column error`.

This is the same principle as when working with DELETE and UPDATE statements, because the typical syntax doesn't allow you to alias the table being deleted or updated.

Comment: true, but most of the times we often not use aliases when working with a single table in particular when using IN clause. When dealing with Migration scripts converting data from different sources, this SQL behavior would hurt when aliases are not used. But thank you for pointing it out, I would make it a point to use aliases.

Comment: @user1141441: Yes, situations like this are exactly why I am so adamant about table alias usage.